# gRPC memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, grpc

My Visual Studio project, that use gRPC library have memory leaks. After some R&D I made a little project   to reproduce the problem and found that don't even need to call any gRPC object in my code.
My steps:

1) Get `helloworld.proto` from examples

2) Generate C++ files

3) Create C++ project with next code:

```
#include "helloworld.grpc.pb.h"

void f(){
  helloworld::HelloRequest request;
}

int main(){
  _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
  return 0;
}
```

Part of Output(full dump have 240 lines):

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{1450} normal block at 0x00FD77A0, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <`{   t   C   |  > 60 7B FD 00 20 74 FD 00 84 43 CA 00 88 7C CA 00 
{1449} normal block at 0x00FECA30, 48 bytes long.
 Data: <google.protobuf.> 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 2E 70 72 6F 74 6F 62 75 66 2E 
{1448} normal block at 0x00FEA048, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <        > 20 C6 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{1447} normal block at 0x00FEC610, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < v  p"   v      > B8 76 FC 00 70 22 FE 00 B8 76 FC 00 00 00 CD CD 
{1441} normal block at 0x00FEA610, 32 bytes long.
 Data: <google.protobuf.> 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 2E 70 72 6F 74 6F 62 75 66 2E 
{1440} normal block at 0x00FE9B78, 8 bytes long.
```

If I add `google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary();` line before `return 0;`, I will have much less output. Only that:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{160} normal block at 0x00FCD858, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <    > 18 D6 B9 00 
{159} normal block at 0x00FCD618, 4 bytes long.
 Data: < >  > C8 3E B9 00 
{158} normal block at 0x00FCD678, 4 bytes long.
 Data: < ?  > D0 3F B9 00 
Object dump complete.
```

But if I include some addition generated sources with many and big `services` and `messages`, memory dump will be much bigger.

So since I really don't use any gRPC objects directly, only one think I can imagine is that some `static` objects still alive when VS Memory Dumper start to work.

Is there a way to fix it or a suggestion what I can do with that?

**UPD:**

I made some addition work around this problem and open new issue on grpc repository bug tracker: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/22506

Problem Description on that issue contain screenshots with leaked allocations callstack and gRPC debug traces.

**UPD2:**

I found all of them(1.23.0 version). I leaved the detailed comment there: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/22506#issuecomment-618406755

Comment: Indeed, it might happen that there are some global objects that own memory to be freed after the call of _CrtSetDbgFlag. Have you tried to debug with a profiler like Deleaker? No call stacks in the output...

Comment: Yes, I used Memory Usage Diagnostic Tool from Visual Studio. It helped me to understood, that we always should call `google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary();` in the end of our applications(I can give you detailed explanation if you have an interest). Also, I updated this topic with url to issue opened by me on bug tracker with callstack screenshots